# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync throws an error

Tags: c#

i was trying to create and run the sample project given in this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet).
here is the code:

```
namespace GmailQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Gmail API service.
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

            // Define parameters of request.
            UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");

            // List labels.
            IList<Label> labels= request.Execute().Labels;
            Console.WriteLine("Labels:");
            if (labels != null && labels.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var labelItem in labels)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", labelItem.Name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No labels found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

after i have done everything stated in google's documentation, including issuing a secrets.json file for my application/product, i ran it.
It fails with an exception, containing a "An invalid argument was supplied" inner exception.
I have retried everything with a new acocunt given new api credentials, etc., and still same error occurs. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What are the arguments being passed, plus what is the code? It is hard to help you with english-only description. :-)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan - Updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets()
{
    ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
    ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET
};

var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = REFRESH_TOKEN }; 
var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer 
    {
        ClientSecrets = secrets
    }), 
    "user", 
    token);

var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
    ApplicationName = "ApplicationName"
});
```

Comment: Already done that. this one fails with an error saying "Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section." when i try to execute the list request. what should be the value of  REFRESH_TOKEN ? how do i create/get it?